# trouble saving numpy array to matlab readable file

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I have an image sequence as a numpy array;
Mov (15916, 480, 768)
dtype = int16

i've tried using `Mov.tofile(filename)`
this saves the array and I can load it again in python and view the images.
In matlab the images are corrupted after about 3000 frames.
Using the following also works but has the same problem when I retrieve the images in matlab;
`fp = np.memmap(sbxpath, dtype='int16', mode='w+', shape=Mov.shape)`
`fp[:,:,:] = Mov[:,:,:]`

If I use:
`mv['mov'] = Mov`
`sio.savemat(sbxpath, mv)`

I get the following error;
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for this, because it is a beginners problem. Python saves variables as integers or floats depending on how they are initialized. Matlab defaults to 8 byte doubles. My matlab script expects doubles, my python script was outputting all kinds of variable types, so naturally things got messed up.